# Submitted data doesn't get stored in database and i get redirected after submit

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5

Hi i am working on php Laravel,and i am trying to submit data from a modal,and i want it to,simply close the modal after submission is successful,not redirect.But neither is working,so after submit i am being redirected,and after submit,there is no added data into the database.

So after filling the data in the form,press submit,it redirects me to the `\` page,and i check the database,nothing is added.I can however extract data from it,so it's not the connection or the config.

I want to stay on the same page after submitting,with just closing the modal(i will disply a success later).

This is my in-modal form :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-body">  

        <form id="eventForm" method="post" action="createEvent">
            //a couple inputs
            //a submit button
        </form>
   </div
</div>
```

This is the jQuery handling the data submission and non redirection

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#eventForm')
      .formValidation({
           framework: 'bootstrap',
          //icon,fields validation
       })            
      .on('success.form.bv', function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
          var $form = $("#eventForm"),
          url = $form.attr('action');
           $.post(url, $form.serialize()).done(function () {
               $("#myModal").dialog("close");
            });
            });
            });
```

My route

```
 route::post('createEvent' , 'EventsController@store');
```

The controller handling the request

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $event= new event();

    //retrieving the data here

    $event->name = $request->name;
    $event->description = $request->description;
    $event->ending_date = $request->ending_date;
    $event->starting_date = $request->starting_date;
    $event->assigned_to = $request->assigned_to;
    $event->save();
}
```

The namespacing and uses are correct but i can post them if you want.
Any suggestions ?

**Update**

In the developpers tools,i checked the network section,i found out that the request is being sent,but simply 302 redirected,and the javascript code is not executing,so its being submitted as i hit the submit button.

Trying to console.log the javascript code,made me realize it is not even being executed,but still the submission,not reaching the page is another problem to solve.

Comment: What do you see in the network tab of developer tools? Is ajax request being made properly? What is the return value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have CSRF tokens check ? If so,please either include your token when posting,like this :

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

and in the form as a field like this :

```
<form method="POST" action="/profile">

{{ csrf_field() }}
...
</form>
```

Or by excluding your route from being csrf checked,like this (check your VerifyCsrToken.php)

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
  /**
   * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $except = [
      'stripe/*',
  ];
}
```

check these [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/csrf) they should explain things more to you.

When you said it redirects always to `\` that meant,it checked if checked if you were logged in or not,since it could not check the csrf token(that you did not include).

**UPDATED**

As for the submit,i don't know why it doesn't stop submitting,but i tried

```
$("#formi_id").submit(function(e){
return false;
});
```

or check this [working example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MadxaE).
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you this worked out for me,it saved me ! though i am having a duplicated post,the second one gets 500 nternal server,any ideas about that?